# How can one avoid too many numbers after the decimalpoint?

Tags: javascript, math

The following code generates numbers and than divides it with 1000:
But some times numbers like 1.2295999999999998 are generated, while 1229.6 is only being divided by 1000?

What do I need to change in the code, so that this does not occur?

```js
Z1 = document.getElementById("Z1").innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99899 + 100)) / Math.pow(10, Math.floor((Math.random() * 3 + 1)));

document.getElementById("L").innerHTML = Z1 / 1000;
```

```html
<label id="Z1"></label><br>
<label id="L"></label>
```

Comment: Use `toFixed(n)`.

Comment: [Please see this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439981/11910438)

Comment: @SuperStar you should flag to close as a duplicate if you feel the question has been asked (and answered) before

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("L").innerHTML = (Z1 / 1000).toFixed(2); 
// if you want 2 digits after decimalpoint
```

Further Explaination:

Floating point numbers cannot represent all decimals precisely in binary. It has to do with how decimal values are converted to binary floating point numbers. For example, 1/10 turns into a repeating decimal in binary, so the number is not perfectly represented, and repeated operations can expose the error.